# Why is Apache <If> statement causing all my FilesMatch directives to be ignored?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.4

### Background

The main Apache config file comes with rules to block viewing of .htaccess files. I have some other `<FilesMatch>` directives of my own. I know these all work, as is.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

In the `.htaccess` at the root of my website I require authentication:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorised Access Only"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

This works absolutely fine. If I try to view the `.htaccess`, for example, I get forbidden. If I try to access any other page of the site, I am prompted to authenticate.

---

### The Problem

However, I want to use a condition based on my Apache environment variable so that the authentication is only active on my staging environment:

```
<If "env('ENV_NAME') == 'stag'">
    AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Authorised Access Only"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

I also know this works in itself. However, as soon as I add the `<If>` statement around the Auth block, all of my `<FilesMatch>` statements stop working and it's like the authentication allows all of them to bypassed.

Once I have the `<If>` statement and try to view my `.htaccess` in the browser, I am asked to authenticate, and then I can view the file.

---

### What I want to achieve

I want to be able to maintain my conditional authentication based on the environment variable, but still require all the `<FilesMatch>` security directives to be honoured.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replace `<If>` with `Require expr "env('ENV_NAME') != 'stag'"` but the function `env` seems to not recognize variables defined by `SetEnv`. Only `<If>` seems to do so but there are some expression evaluation specificities.

I also tried some combinations of `<Require(All|Any|None)>` at different level to finaly make it with a simple `AuthMerging And`.

So, my suggestion and answer is to add `AuthMerging And` in your .htaccess

Because I'm really not a huge fan of anubhava's answer if you have to duplicate any higher-level logic that you even might not know in the first place in the .htaccess.

EDIT: in fact, it might be a better idea to put `AuthMerging And` directly in the `<FilesMatch "^\.ht">` block instead of the .htaccess itself.

Comment: You might need to set the variable with `SetEnvIf` for it to be available - e.g. `SetEnvIf Host ^ ENV_NAME=stag`. I agree the duplication of the logic is not a good solution. I'll  look into auth merging.

Comment: "it might be a better idea to put `AuthMerging And` directly in the `<FilesMatch`" - That won't work here, since the `<If>` container changes the order of processing. The `AuthMerging And` directive would need to go in the `.htaccess` file (as mentioned earlier) _and_ inside the `<If>` container. `AuthMerging` only refers to the _preceding_ config section.

Answer (score 0):

The `<If>` container changes the order of processing. `<If>` containers are merged *very late*, after the `<FilesMatch>` container, so the `Require valid-user` essentially **overrides** the `Require all denied` set in Apache config. However, **without the `<If>` container**, the `.htaccess` directives are processed early and the `<FilesMatch>` container is merged later, overriding the `Require valid-user` directive.

However, there is no need to use `<if>` directive here for enforcing auth for `stag` environment. You can use [Apache 2.4 `Require` and `RequireAny` directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) to achieve this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorised Access Only"
<RequireAny>
   Require expr "env('ENV_NAME') != 'stag'"
   Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

This will enforce auth only when an env variable `ENV_NAME` is not equal to `stag` due to presence of `RequireAny` block that requires any of the `Require` conditions to be true.

---

**Alternatively**, you may add another condition in your `<If>` expression to make this block execute only for requests that are not starting with `/.ht` like this:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/\.ht# && env('ENV_NAME') == 'stag'">
    AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Authorised Access Only"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why it works correctly without the `<If>` condition though. Wouldn't the `Require valid-user` still override the Apache config? Is there a more practical way to do this without replicating every other `FilesMatch` directive I might have elsewhere in the config, as part of the condition here?

Comment: "It is not happening due to `<if` condition" - Well, it kind of is. The `<If>` container changes the order of processing. `<If>` containers are merged _very late_, after the `<FilesMatch>` container, so the `Require valid-user` essentially overrides the `Require all denied` (as stated). However, without the `<If>` container, the `.htaccess` directives are processed early and the `<FilesMatch>` container is merged later, overriding the `Require valid-user` directive. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging

Comment: Thanks so much @MrWhite for great explanation. You are right on the money.

Comment: @BadHorsie: Sorry to respond late, somehow I missed your comment below my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite: I have updated answer with use of `RequireAny` instead of `<If>` and in my testing everything appears to be working as desired.

Comment: @MrWhite: I have copied part of your explanation in comment into my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BadHorsie: Did you get a chance to try my updated answer?